# java method execution with no parameters or return

Tags: java, methods

The problem I am having is with the last method in this program. I am not able to get it to execute the message it is required to execute the right way. 
The last method, displayData needs to display the message with the variables from getLength, getWidth, and getArea within the method, not the main. What can I do to get the variables to be displayed?

```
//Gabby
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AreaRectangle
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      double length = getLength();
      double width = getWidth();
      double area = getArea(length, width);
      displayData(double l, double w, double a);
   }
   public static double getLength()
   {  
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      double l;
      System.out.print("Please enter a value for length: ");
      l = keyboard.nextDouble();
      return l;
   }
   public static double getWidth()
   {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      double w;
      System.out.print("Please enter a value for width: ");
      w = keyboard.nextDouble();
      return w;
   }
   public static double getArea(double length, double width)
   {
      double a;
      a = length * width;
      return a;
   }    
   public static void displayData(l, w, a)
   {
      System.out.print("Length is: " + l);
      System.out.print("Width is: " + w);
      System.out.print("Area is: " + a);
   }
```

}

Error Messages:

```
 ----jGRASP exec: javac -g AreaRectangle.java

AreaRectangle.java:11: error: '.class' expected
      displayData(double l, double w, double a);
                         ^
AreaRectangle.java:11: error: ';' expected
      displayData(double l, double w, double a);
                          ^
AreaRectangle.java:11: error: <identifier> expected
      displayData(double l, double w, double a);
                                     ^
AreaRectangle.java:11: error: not a statement
      displayData(double l, double w, double a);
                                             ^
AreaRectangle.java:11: error: ';' expected
      displayData(double l, double w, double a);
                                              ^
AreaRectangle.java:35: error: <identifier> expected
   public static void displayData(l, w, a)
                                   ^
AreaRectangle.java:35: error: <identifier> expected
   public static void displayData(l, w, a)
                                      ^
AreaRectangle.java:35: error: <identifier> expected
   public static void displayData(l, w, a)
                                         ^
8 errors

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Comment: `public static void displayData(l, w, a)` is not a valid method signature.

Comment: Ahh, good 'ol jGrasp.

Answer (score 1):

**More generally, method declarations have six components, in order:**

> **1**. Modifiers—such as public, private, and others you will learn about later.
>
> **2**. The return type—the data type of the value returned by the method, or void if the method does not return a value.
>
> **3**. The method name—the rules for field names apply to method names as well, but the convention is a little different.
>
> **4**. The parameter list in parenthesis—a comma-delimited list of input parameters, preceded by their data types, enclosed by
>   parentheses, (). If there are no parameters, you must use empty
>   parentheses.
>
> **5**. An exception list—to be discussed later.
>
> **6**. The method body, enclosed between braces—the method's code, including the declaration of local variables, goes here.

In your method declaration here

```
public static void displayData(l, w, a){
```

**you forgot to apply step 4 of the common rules**

```
 public static void displayData(double l, double w, double a){
```

**Note**: is it a good practiced to override `toString` method

Answer (score 1):

Well when we call a method we dont specify argument type we juste pass values so in the main method:
**Replace this:** displayData(double l, double w, double a);
**By this:** displayData(length, width, area);
Meanwhile in the display Data  method declaration do the following:
**Replace this:**

```
public static void displayData(l, w, a)
   {
      System.out.print("Length is: " + l);
      System.out.print("Width is: " + w);
      System.out.print("Area is: " + a);
   }
```

**By this:**

```
public static void displayData(double l, double w, double a)
   {
      System.out.print("Length is: " + l);
      System.out.print("Width is: " + w);
      System.out.print("Area is: " + a);
   }
```

### /!\ **YOU MUST PAY ATTENTION - READ THE FOLLOWING** /!\

The main method is static, when you put your code in it all the outer members called inside the main method must be static, the best way to do it is like this:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class AreaRectangle {

      public AreaRectangle() {
       //Call all methods you want
         double length = getLength();
         double width = getWidth();
         double area = getArea(length, width);
         displayData(length, width, area);
      }

      public double getLength() {  
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double l;
        System.out.print("Please enter a value for length: ");
        l = keyboard.nextDouble();
        return l;
      }

      public double getWidth() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double w;
        System.out.print("Please enter a value for width: ");
        w = keyboard.nextDouble();
        return w;
      }
      public double getArea(double length, double width) {
        double a;
        a = length * width;
        return a;
      }    
      public void displayData(double l, double w, double a) {
        System.out.print("Length is: " + l);
        System.out.print("Width is: " + w);
        System.out.print("Area is: " + a);
      }

      public static void main(String[] args){
        new AreaRectangle();
      }
    }
```

Remember, in static context (the main method) you can call only static members.
If you do it like this, you don't need to use static keyword in all class members. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass they type, pass just the variable names.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  double length = getLength();
  double width = getWidth();
  double area = getArea(length, width);
  displayData(length, width, area);
}
```

The signature of `displayData()` should instead be:

```
public static void displayData(double l, double w, double a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke your method like `displayData(length, width, area);` and define it like `public static void displayData(double l, double w, double a) {...}`

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void displayData(l, w, a)
```

In java you need to provide a type for each parameter in your methods, this isnt JavaScript :)

Answer (score 0):

Below are the mistakes. Mthod Signature not defined correctly.

1.) `displayData(length, width, area);`

2.)  `public static void displayData(double l, double w, double a) {`

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        double length = getLength();
        double width = getWidth();
        double area = getArea(length, width);
        displayData(length, width, area);
    }

    public static double getLength() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double l;
        System.out.print("Please enter a value for length: ");
        l = keyboard.nextDouble();
        return l;
    }

    public static double getWidth() {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        double w;
        System.out.print("Please enter a value for width: ");
        w = keyboard.nextDouble();
        return w;
    }

    public static double getArea(double length, double width) {
        double a;
        a = length * width;
        return a;
    }

    public static void displayData(double l, double w, double a) {
        System.out.print("Length is: " + l);
        System.out.print("Width is: " + w);
        System.out.print("Area is: " + a);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change your method to this

```
 public static void displayData(double l, double w, double a)
   {
      System.out.print("Length is: " + l);
      System.out.print("Width is: " + w);
      System.out.print("Area is: " + a);
   }
```

and then in your main do this

```
displayData(length, width, area);
```

Comment: note: methods have the data types in the params section, but when you call the method you pass in variables and don't need to define the types.

Answer (score 0):

You have your formal parameters and actual parameters mixed up. A *formal parameter* includes the type of each parameter, while an *actual paramater* is the real value you are passing.

When you are calling a method, actual parameters are needed (type can be omitted). Therefore this:

```
displayData(double l, double w, double a);
```

should be changed to this:

```
displayData(length, width, area);
```

---

When you are defining a method, formal parameters are used. This:

```
public static void displayData(l, w, a)
```

should be changed to include the type of each parameter:

```
public static void displayData(double l, double w, double a)
```